# How to filter the dynamic Json data using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, underscore.js

I have an array of json objects with dynamic data in it i.e both the keys and values are dynamic as :

```
arr=[{"a":"email"},{"b":"chat"},{"c":"email"},{"d":"chat"},{"e":"email"}]
```

The size of arr may change i.e it may have any number of json objects.

How do I filter the data using underscore.js ??

This is what I was trying to do :

```
  filterData(searchValue:string){
        this.skillGrpsFilteredData= _.filter(this.skillGroupsAndTypes, function(obj) {
        return ~obj.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) as any;
      }); 
  }
```

But this approach is not working as the keys in the above array obj is dynamic i.e "a,b,c,d,e,.." are dynamic in nature.
And searchValue is the value that comes from the frontend UI.

How do I perform search using keys i.e if I type searchValue=a it should give me that object and so on .

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Try `Object.keys(obj).includes(searchValue)`?

Comment: @MaheerAli Hi, includes is working but what if I want to use something like indexOf because , let's say if I type "a" , then I want to filter out all the names having a in them , similarly if I type another character I want to filter of based on that , but with "Object.keys(item)" indexOf is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Following function filters array objects containing the search value both in key and value of the object 
in your case you can pass 'a' or "email" to get the objects

```
 function searchObject(array , searchValue){
    return array.filter(item=>{ return Object.keys(item).includes(searchValue) ||Object.values(item).includes(searchValue)})
}

let arr=[{"a":"email"},{"b":"chat"},{"c":"email"},{"d":"chat"},{"e":"email"}]
console.log(searchObject(arr,'a'));
```

if you want just to filter by key and not by value of the object remove the

```
Object.values(item).includes(searchValue)
```

from the or condition

if you want to try indexOf 
try

```
function searchObject(array , searchValue){
    return array.filter(item=>{ return 
    Object.keys(item).indexOf(searchValue)>=0})
}
```

Comment: Hi, includes is working but what if I want to use something like indexOf because , let's say if I type "a" , then I want to filter out all the names having a in them , similarly if I type another character I want to filter of based on that , but with "Object.keys(item)" indexOf is not working.

Comment: by having a  do you mean "aa" can also be a key ? and if you want to use indexof try this   function searchObject(array , searchValue){
    return array.filter(item=>{ return Object.keys(item).indexOf(searchValue)>=0})
}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function. In the *array parameter* you can pass arr=[{"a":"email"},{"b":"chat"},{"c":"email"},{"d":"chat"},{"e":"email"}] and in *searchKey parameter* pass such as "a" it will return {"a":"email"}. If match not found function will return null

```
searchByKey(array,searchKey ) {
        for (let obj of array) {
          for (let key in obj) {
            if (key == searchKey) {
             return obj;
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
```